# Alphabet list not load all

Tags: jquery

I can only manage to load the first letter "A" by using .each() function, but the rest of letters are not looped out. I want the first letter (alphabet) of each category name to be in the alphabet list.

```js
$(function($){ 

var letters = [];
$("<ul></ul>").appendTo(".page-content").html("<li></li>");

$("nav.link-list a").each(function(i){
    var brandTitle = $(this).attr("title");
         itmLetter =  brandTitle.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    console.log(letters);
    console.log(itmLetter);
    if (letters.indexOf(itmLetter)<0) {
                letters.push(itmLetter);
      console.log(`${itmLetter} is not in ${letters} and index is ${i}`);
      $(`.page-content li:nth-child(${i+1})`).addClass("AddContent").attr({'id': itmLetter, 'data-content' : itmLetter});
        
    } else {
     console.log(`${itmLetter} is in ${letters}`);
    }
}); // end of each() function
   
}); // end of jQuery function
```

```css
.AddContent:before {
   content: attr(data-content);
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <h1>Brands</h1>
  <div class="page-content__body"></div>
</div>
<article class="category-list">
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="ABUS">ABUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="ACC">ACC</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BUS">BUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BKUS">BKUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="KUS">KUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="SUK">SUK</a>
    </nav>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean

```js
$(function($) {
  var letters = [];
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo(".page-content");

  $("nav.link-list a").each(function(i) {
    var brandTitle = $(this).attr("title");
    itmLetter = brandTitle.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    if (letters.indexOf(itmLetter) < 0) {
      letters.push(itmLetter);
      $ul.append(
        $("<li/>", {
          "class": "AddContent",
          "id": itmLetter,
          "data-content": itmLetter
        })
      )
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.AddContent:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <h1>Brands</h1>
  <div class="page-content__body"></div>
</div>
<article class="category-list">
  <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="ABUS">ABUS</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="ACC">ACC</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="BUS">BUS</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="BKUS">BKUS</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="KUS">KUS</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="link-list">
    <a href="/brands/abus" title="SUK">SUK</a>
  </nav>
</article>
```